# Automatic building and installing Packages from AUR for Arch Linux inside Docker with yaourt and >makepkg-4.2.0

Tags: docker, archlinux

I'm using Docker and Arch Linux inside the Docker-Container.
Introducing **makepkg-4.2.0** my Installation Command with yaourt were broken like described here: https://github.com/archlinuxfr/yaourt/issues/67

The Problem is, that yaourt should be run as non-root user. But as yaourt wants also to install the Package in every Case, after it has built it, root user is needed or a user that has the Permission to install Packages.

So my Question ist how to solve this? I want to install a Package from AUR inside the Docker, because no official Package exists yet.

Until now i was using Arch Linux, pacman and yaourt.

So the Command,

```
RUN yaourt -S --noconfirm aur/taskd
```

that installs taskd, worked before makepkg-4.2.0:

With the new makepkg Version building the Docker fails with the following Error from yaourt:

```
makepkg: invalid option '--asroot'
```

If i change the user to a non-root User and try to install the Package i get a Command prompt in my automated build asking for the Root-Password for actually installing the Package.

```
Password: su: Authentication information cannot be recovered
Password: su: Authentication information cannot be recovered
Password: su: Authentication information cannot be recovered
The command [/bin/sh -c yaourt -S --noconfirm aur/taskd] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Without polluting to many offtopic Lines spread over two Dockerfiles, the interesting Portion of the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM kaot/arch_linux_base:latest
MAINTAINER Kaot
RUN useradd --no-create-home --shell=/bin/false yaourt && usermod -L yaourt
RUN yaourt -S --noconfirm aur/taskd
ENTRYPOINT ["/controlcenter/controlcenter.sh"]
CMD ["cc:start"]
```

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile or a reproducer?

Comment: @user2915097: I added a minimal Dockerfile, that should contains the important Lines, leaving out the offtopic Lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If found a Solution that let yaourt only download the Info how to build the Package, then invoke makepkg itself, both with an non-root User and afterwards install the build Package with the root User and pacman.
The Portion of the Dockerfile looks like this

```
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/Package/ && chown yaourt /tmp/Package
USER yaourt
RUN cd /tmp/Package && pwd && ls -al && yaourt --getpkgbuild aur/taskd && cd taskd && makepkg --pkg taskd 
USER root
RUN pacman -U --noconfirm /tmp/Package/taskd/taskd-1.1.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

With some Variables, further Enhancements could be achieved, but in Principle this works.